How could a scan tool disable the car through the DLC?
I recently bought an Innova scan tool. I don't work on cars very often, but I needed a basic scan tool. It worked fine for a month or so, then just stopped connecting to vehicles. I have a 2006 Jeep Liberty as my daily driver and was playing with it, trying to get the Innova to connect. What happened is, with the Innova plugged in, I tried to start the Jeep, and it wouldn't run. It would turn over with the starter motor but not run. When I unplugged the Innova, the car started just fine. So, the Innova did something to prevent the car from starting. There's the K-line, the can bus and the 1850 bus on the DLC, as far as I know. My question is, what could that scanner have done to prevent the car from starting? Thank you.

My guess; pin-16 is 12v power to readers/scantools and if the tool fails, may pull down or blow the 12v fused line from the car. If your Innova has internal software failure or damaged connector pins, signals to/from a vehicle may disrupt the EFI system, preventing engine running. Since you already know disconnecting your scantool allows engine startup, stop using it. Either consider sending it out for repair or buy another scantool.

I made a video that I sent to Innova showing what their tool did to my car. Best case scenario, I get refunded, but I'm guessing it'll only end up in a warranty repair deal. Anyway, I used my Autoenginuity to find out the codes it generated, and it looks like the tool shorted out my CAN bus. I had codes for failure of the CAN bus, fuel level, A/C switch, and another I forgot at the moment. $300 down the tubes. I should just get an Autel. Here's the link to vid. https://youtu.be/3WksgBYJ5To?si=tou9_2B-54n3HR2W

Fortunately for you, the damage to your electronics wasn't permanent and you were able to restore engine functions and use another scantool to continue diagnosing. Whether or not the temporary damage created additional error codes may be determined if you can keep a perspective of what started, then became side tracked. Maybe Innova, as a good gesture, may offer to send you a replacement, free of charge and ask you to send the errant one back to them for analysis.

Yes! In fact, while I was posting here, I was emailing them. They have a one email message a day capacity, apparently. I now have an RMA number and am sending the unit back for repair. No telling how long that's going to take, but hopefully I'll have it back at some point soon. Thanks for your help!
